# Flex/ActionScript Change Shape Fill Color

Tags: actionscript, colortransform

Here is the code I have:

```
private function drawRect():Sprite{
   var rect:Sprite = new Sprite();
   rect.name = "rectName";
   rect.graphics.beginFill(0xffff00);
   rect.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000);
   rect.graphics.drawRect(0,0,6,6);
   rect.graphics.endFill();
   rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, changeColor);
   rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, changeColorBack);
   return rect;
}

private function changeColor(e:MouseEvent):void{
   var newColor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
   newColor.color = 0x00ffff;
   e.target.transform.colorTransform = newColor;
}

private function changeColorBack(e:MouseEvent):void{
   var newColor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
   newColor.color = 0xffff00;
   e.target.transform.colorTransform = newColor;
}
```

The changeColor and changeColorBack functions work but not how I would like them to.  They change the whole color of my Sprite including the line border(stroke) around the rectangle.  I want to change just the color inside the rectangle and maintain the rectangle's border.  I don't see a property in the ColorTransform that allows me to specify the lineStyle so is there a different approach to changing the fill color of my rectagle and maintain the border around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColorTransform` applies to the whole `MovieClip` regardless of what's drawn in its graphics property. You could either redraw the rectangle each time you need to:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

function drawRect(target:Sprite, clr:Number):void{
   target.graphics.clear();
   target.graphics.beginFill(clr);
   target.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000);
   target.graphics.drawRect(0,0,6,6);
   target.graphics.endFill();
}

function changeColor(e:MouseEvent):void{
   drawRect(Sprite(e.target), 0x00ffff);
}

function changeColorBack(e:MouseEvent):void{
   drawRect(Sprite(e.target), 0xffff00);
}

var rect:Sprite = new Sprite();
rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, changeColor);
rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, changeColorBack);
this.addChild(rect);

drawRect(rect, 0xffff00);
```

Or, if you're set on using `ColorTransform` for some reason, you could build your outlined rectangle out of two separate `Sprites` (an outer and an inner) and target the inner `Sprite` only with the `ColorTransform`:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

function getRectangle(w:Number, h:Number, x:Number, y:Number, clr:Number):Sprite{
   var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
   sprite.name = "rectName";
   sprite.graphics.beginFill(clr);
   sprite.graphics.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
   sprite.graphics.endFill();

   return sprite;
}

function changeColor(e:MouseEvent):void{
   var newColor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
   newColor.color = 0x00ffff;
   inner.transform.colorTransform = newColor;
}

function changeColorBack(e:MouseEvent):void{
   var newColor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
   newColor.color = 0xffff00;
   inner.transform.colorTransform = newColor;
}

var rect:Sprite = new Sprite();
rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, changeColor);
rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, changeColorBack);
this.addChild(rect);

// Outer rectangle for the outline
var outer:Sprite = getRectangle(8, 8, 0, 0, 0x000000);
rect.addChild(outer);

// Smaller inner rectangle which can be targeted with the color transform
var inner:Sprite = getRectangle(6, 6, 1, 1, 0xffff00);
rect.addChild(inner);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had thought of both of these solutions but as of this posting didn't implement them.  I was hoping to not have to redraw or create another child sprite.  For now I think it's a bit easier for me to add a sprite around the square.

Comment: I actually went with the first option of redrawing the square.